# Cannot open browse in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, openfiledialog

I have a DataGridView as seen in the picture and a OpenFileDialog has to open when I click on  "Browse from file". I believe there is no way to become possible if i write my code under the button_Click methods but i dont know under which method to write my code. Please help.

[image]

As far as now I have made this: (hope it helps)

```
string[] col2 = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

            if (col2[i] == "Browse From File...")
            {
                DialogResult result2 = openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();
                if (result2 == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                     filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                }
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Path appears in the Dropdown menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648511/path-appears-in-the-dropdown-menu)

Answer (score 1):

Place your code in the `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event. Use the `SelectedCells` property to find the current cell, then check if its value is "Browse From File...". If so, fire off the `OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()` call.

See this documentation for CellValueChanged: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx

Comment: As far as now I am here: `// if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells = "Browse From File...")   
          { }

           if (dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells["Browse From File..."].Value.ToString() == "Browse From File...")
           {

               openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();

           }` **Please help mate.** Cant understand how the SelectedCells is going to work so i tried with `Rows.Cells.Value.ToString`

Comment: SelectedCells is just a list of selected cells. SelectedCells[0].Value will give you the value of the cell that's currently selected, if you've got one selected.

Comment: `private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {`    `if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value == "Browse From File...")` `{openFileDialog2.ShowDialog();}`  Nothing happens with this code I wrote you.

Comment: Try `[0].Value.ToString() ==`

Comment: I tried that to before you tell me! haha. Cool eh? In both cases it prints me a **warning** _Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'_

Comment: Cast it to string then. `(string)dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value == "Browse From File..."`

Comment: Now I have no warnings but when I click on the Browse From File , the openfileDIalog does not open.